# pg_restore not working for .dump file

Tags: postgresql, dump, database-backups, database-restore, pg-dump

I'm trying to restore a database to a new environment and pg_dump/pg_restore seems like the best way for me to do that.

I've run the pg_dump command with the following code which has produced my dump file:

```
pg_dump -v -Fc --host=test.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=test@test --dbname=test > test.dump
```

However when I run pg_restore it is not able to restore the database. I have run into two separate errors when trying two separate commands. The first error

[image: pg_error1]

occurs when i use the following command

```
pg_restore -h test.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U test@test -C test.dump
```

and the second

[image]

occurs upon using this command

```
pg_restore -h test.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U test@test -C -Fc test.dump
```

I really don't understand what is going wrong here. All other answers I have found that get these same errors were encountered when people tried to restore plain text files but that's not what I'm attempting to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to specify the output file for `pg_dump` using the `--file` option instead of redirecting the output - could be a problem with writing binary data to stdout

Comment: this worked a charm feel free to add it as an answer and i can accept it